# Изменить цвет меток и засечек осей в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Сделал в калькуляторе с режимом построения графиков тёмную тему, теперь нужно изменить цвета. В целом всё окей, только мне бы узнать, как изменить цвет единичных отрезков? Имею в виду 10.0, 7.5, 5.0, 2.5, 0.0 и по оси x тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кусочек кода:

```py
text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
self.ui.layoutCanvasWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 150, 331, 321))
fig = Figure()
graph = fig.add_subplot()
x = numpy.around(numpy.arange(-10, 10.1, 0.1), decimals=4)
try:
    y = eval(self.replace_(text))
except:
    self.ui.lineEdit.setText('Ошибка')
    self.result_status = True
    return
try:
    graph.plot(x, y, color = '#E1E1E1')
    graph.autoscale(tight = True)
except:
    graph.plot([-10, 10], [y, y], color = '#E1E1E1')
    graph.set_xlim(-10, 10)
    graph.set_ylim(y-10, y+10)
graph.grid(True, color = '#000000')
graph.set_facecolor('#505050')
fig.set_facecolor('#373737')
canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(fig)
self.ui.layoutCanvas.addWidget(canvas)
```

Comment: Что за "единичные отрезки"? Цвет сетки и подписи по осям, чтоли?

Comment: Так тему-то, видать, не ты сделал. Потому что если бы сделал сам, то знал бы, где у тебя определяется цвет "единичных отрезков", который тут явно указан.

Comment: Ты сам-то понял, что я тебе написал? Где я говорил про какой-то стайлшит? У тебя в коде прямо указан черный цвет.

Comment: @Эникейщик чёрный цвет указан к сетке, а не к единичным отрезкам

Comment: Тебя сразу в первом комментарии спросили, что такое "единичный отрезок". Если придумываешь какие-то свои названия, то будь добр объяснять нормальным людям, что они означают.

Comment: Гугл в помощь, что ж. Прям так пишешь: "Что такое единичный отрезок?"

Comment: @Эникейщик специально, чтобы никто не путался я в 3 предложении написал пример

Comment: Пример чего? Отрезок - это линия. А ты там написал числа. Вот я тебе и указал на линии под этими числами.

Comment: @Эникейщик так или иначе единичный отрезок это общепринятый термин

Comment: Ага. Только в общепринятом зачем он на этом графике отсутствует.

Comment: @Эникейщик загугли, что такое единичных отрезок еще раз

Comment: Вот и загугли, хоть узнаешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, лучше придерживаться принятых соглашений именования элементов и модулей. для изменения цвета меток, осей и засечек можно сделать так:

```py
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('#ffffff')
#ax.spines['top'].set_color('#ffffff')
ax.xaxis.label.set_color('#ffffff')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='#ffffff')

ax.spines['left'].set_color('#ffffff')
#ax.spines['right'].set_color('#ffffff')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('#ffffff')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='#ffffff')
```

Подозреваю, что  в вашем случае, вместо `ax` нужно будет писать `graph`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо